# How to setup elasticsearch-rails denormalization mappings

Tags: ruby-on-rails, elasticsearch, denormalization

I am trying to setup mappings for elasticsearch denormalization like the one in [this link](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/denormalization.html)

I have the following models:

**Brand**

```
class Brand < ApplicationRecord
  include Elasticsearch::Model

  # title

  has_and_belongs_to_many :products

  index_name Rails.application.engine_name.split('_').first

  mapping do
    indexes :title, type: 'keyword'
  end
end
```

**Category**

```
class Category < ApplicationRecord
  include Elasticsearch::Model

  # title

  has_many :categorizations
  has_many :products, through: :categorizations

  index_name Rails.application.engine_name.split('_').first

  mapping do
    indexes :title, type: 'keyword'
  end
end
```

**Product**

```
class Product < ApplicationRecord
  include Elasticsearch::Model

  # title
  # description

  has_many :categorizations
  has_many :categories, through: :categorizations
  has_many :variations
  has_and_belongs_to_many :brands

  index_name Rails.application.engine_name.split('_').first

  mapping do
    indexes :id
    indexes :title
    indexes :description

    indexes :brands, type: 'keyword'
    indexes :categories, type: 'keyword'

    indexes :variations  do
      indexes :price, index: :not_analyzed
      indexes :color, index: :not_analyzed
      indexes :size, index: :not_analyzed
    end
  end


  after_commit lambda { __elasticsearch__.index_document },  on: :create
  after_commit lambda { __elasticsearch__.update_document },  on: :update
  after_commit lambda { __elasticsearch__.delete_document },  on: :destroy
end
```

**Variation**

```
class Variation < ApplicationRecord
  include Elasticsearch::Model

  # price
  # color
  # size

  belongs_to :product

  index_name Rails.application.engine_name.split('_').first

  mapping do
    indexes :price, index: :not_analyzed
    indexes :color, index: :not_analyzed
    indexes :size, index: :not_analyzed
  end
end
```

**Searchable Module**

```
module Searchable
  INDEX_NAME = Rails.application.engine_name.split('_').first

  def create_index!(options={})
    client = Product.__elasticsearch__.client
    client.indices.delete index: INDEX_NAME rescue nil if options[:force]

    settings = Product.settings.to_hash.merge Variation.settings.to_hash.merge Brand.settings.to_hash.merge Category.settings.to_hash
    mappings = Product.settings.to_hash.merge Variation.mappings.to_hash.merge Brand.mappings.to_hash.merge Category.mappings.to_hash

    client.indices.create index: INDEX_NAME,
        body: {
            settings: settings.to_hash,
            mappings: mappings.to_hash
        }
  end

  def setup
    Searchable.create_index! force: true
    Product.__elasticsearch__.refresh_index!
  end

  extend self
end
```

When I run it it 200 out of the 30,000 products and without the categories. Where am I going wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I got it

**User**

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
  include Elasticsearch::Model
  has_and_belongs_to_many :blogposts, touch: true

  index_name 'blog'

  mapping do
    indexes :name
    indexes :email
  end

  after_commit lambda { __elasticsearch__.index_document  },  on: :create
  after_touch  lambda { __elasticsearch__.index_document  },  on: :touch
  after_commit lambda { __elasticsearch__.update_document },  on: :update
  after_commit lambda { __elasticsearch__.delete_document },  on: :destroy
end
```

**Blogpost**

```
class Blogpost < ApplicationRecord
  include Elasticsearch::Model
  has_and_belongs_to_many :user, touch: true

  index_name 'blog'

  mapping do
    indexes :title
    indexes :body

    indexes :user do
      indexes :id, type: 'long'
      indexes :name, type: 'string' do
        indexes :raw, type: 'keyword', index: 'not_analyzed'
      end
    end
  end

  def as_indexed_json(options={})
    hash = self.as_json()
    hash['user.id'] = self.user.first.id
    hash['user.name'] = self.user.first.name
    hash
  end


  after_commit lambda { __elasticsearch__.index_document  },  on: :create
  after_touch  lambda { __elasticsearch__.index_document  },  on: :touch
  after_commit lambda { __elasticsearch__.update_document },  on: :update
  after_commit lambda { __elasticsearch__.delete_document },  on: :destroy
end
```

**Searchable Module**
    module Searchable
      INDEX_NAME = 'blog'

```
  def create_index!(options={})
    client = User.__elasticsearch__.client
    client.indices.delete index: INDEX_NAME rescue nil if options[:force]

    settings = User.settings.to_hash.merge Blogpost.settings.to_hash
    mappings = User.mappings.to_hash.merge Blogpost.mappings.to_hash

    client.indices.create index: INDEX_NAME,
                          body: {
                              settings: settings.to_hash,
                              mappings: mappings.to_hash }
  end

  def setup
    Searchable.create_index! force: true

    10.times do
      n = Faker::Name.name
      u = User.create name: n,
                      email: Faker::Internet.free_email(n.split(' ').last)

      rand(1..10).times do
        s = Faker::Lorem.sentence
        u.blogposts.create title: s.split(' ').first, body: s
      end
    end

    User.__elasticsearch__.refresh_index!
  end

  extend self
end
```